# C# Extracting data from Json or DataSets - Porting from Python (Json to Dict)

Tags: c#, python, json, dictionary, dataset

I have the following Python script which I need to port to C#. This gets a JSON response from a URL and then pops it into a dictionary. Then it checks for the data next_page and if there is data (it's not empty) it then returns true. Underneath I'll paste the C# code I have but I'm really struggling to do the final part. I don't know and I certainly don't want to understand the data in the JSON response, I just want to know if the field next_page is there.

```
# Gets JSON response
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))

if response.status_code != 200:
   print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
   exit()

data = response.json()

if(data['next_page']):
   return True
else:
   return False
```

So this is the c# code I've got:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string response = "";

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, password);

    try
    {
        response = client.DownloadString(url);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}

XmlDocument xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "RootObject");
XmlReader xr = new XmlNodeReader(xml);
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Json Data");

ds.ReadXml(xr);
```

From what I've seen on the web DataSets work best when you know what the data inside of it is. I just want to know if there is a field called next_page and if there is, is it empty or does it have data. I'm just struggling to get anything out of the DataSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to include the JSON.net nuget package (http://james.newtonking.com/json) this lets you deserialize the JSON response into a dictionary (or preferably a new class) allowing you to access the response.

eg add this into your try catch after including the library

```
var dict = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(response);
```

Alternativly you could create a new class that represents the expected JSON and deserialize into that

```
public class ResponseObject
{
    public string next_page { get; set; }
}

var responseResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(response);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried the first approach and it isn't able to convert it. I get the following error: JsonReaderException was caught: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'tickets', line 1, position 12.

However your second solution works like a charm!

Comment: that will be because the JSON isn't a simple dictionary, in c# its always better to try and have concrete classes for things link this instead of reading magic strings from a dictionary, you can then pass it around in a type safe manor. The second approach should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, the purpose of this was just to pull a page and then check if there is a next page and pull that, then save the total output, so knowing anything other than the next_page was irrelevant and would have been a huge waste of my time, but that's good to know. Thanks for your help :)